# Using loggers in a static context in Akka actors

Tags: java, logging, static, akka, event-log

I am using Akka's recommended event logging for logging from the actors:

```
public class MyActor extends AbstractActor {
  private final LoggingAdapter logger = Logging.getLogger(getContext().getSystem(), this);

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    // do stuff here
      logger.log("Did Stuff here");

    }).matchAny(unhandled -> unhandled(unhandled)).build();
  }

  public static helperMethodForActorTodoItsJob() {
    // Can't log here because of the static context?
  }
}
```

I understand why it is recommended to use event logging in actors, but how do I log in the static methods? Should I create another logger? How does it affect the performance? Or should I not have static methods in the actors? What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you *can* do is pass the `LoggingAdapter` you get via the `log()` method (that is if you choose to extend `AbstractLoggingActor`) as an argument to your class method. If this is what you *want to* do depends on why you would want it to be static in the first place and/or what the method does.